# Is implementing DSs in a flutter app possible?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm ready to start my journey as a flutter dev, the only thing that's holding me back is not having any idea of implementing advance "data-structures" like (stack, linked-list, graph etc) in my Flutter application because there isn't a single tutorial explaining how & I can't afford hiring a teacher.

• Are all the popular DSs available in Dart and with good documentation ?

• If Q1's answer is 'NO' then Can i implement these DSs in Dart all by my own as a beginner ? (I guess I'm someone in middle of the beginner & intermediate stage)

Comment: These are not available in Flutter, because most of the cases can be easily solved with existing lis/map/dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

As you were told in Reddit, you generally don't need those computer-science-education data structures.  Typically a Map or a List is implemented underneath with some of these technologies, but you should need to know or care which ones.